# /WEB-INF/classes vs /WEB-INF/lib

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee

I'd like to package my `Java EE6` web classes (beans, filters, servlets) into jar and place it into `/WEB-INF/lib/` directory along with other utility jars and abandon `/WEB-INF/classes/` directory totally.

Are there any substantial differences between the two in terms of classloading, acessing application context, etc?

Thanks.

PS: Whenever googling any of java specs I'm always redirected to Oracle documentation index which is dozen clicks away from original url. Anyone knows what's happening there?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364619/web-inf-classes-vs-web-inf-lib-jar-in-classpath-priority `WEB-INF/classes/ vs WEB-INF/lib/*.jar in classpath priority?`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd go for `/WEB-INF/classes`. It allows you to run your application in debug mode and hot-swap classes on change. If you package everything as a jar, you'd have to repackage and redeploy the app every time you change a class.

Comment: thanks. But, aside from debugging, will it be functionally the same app?

Answer (score 18):

Well, shortly: Imagine you have class `org.example.Test.class`, if you put it into jar and in  `WEB-INF/lib/` directory, and copy the same class into `WEB-INF/classes/` then classloader of that application will use last one (from `WEB-INF/classes/`).

Sometimes you can use it as advantage - I have a library, and it has a bug... I look for source of that class (where bug is; I miss the part of how I know that bug is in that class, that's another story), I add that class to the project with fixed code, and it is compiled into `WEB-INF/classes/` while library still exist in `WEB-INF/lib/`. Fixed class will be used until library will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks, this feature may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In Tomcat Servlet container's definition: `WEB-INF\classes` is searched before `WEB-INF\lib`. You can choose to delegate your classloading to your custom classloader - even then the order above is maintained.

If you choose to go with a different provider e.g. JBOss, Glassfish, Jetty it might have a different order, but I am not sure about those.