# Where do I place my templates for Blog-related mail notifications in Liferay 7.0?

Tags: liferay-7

The [documentation](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html) states that I can configure the liferay server to use my own templates for the email messages. Specifically, if I add these properties to a `portal-ext-env.properties` in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/liferay`:

```
    blogs.email.entry.added.enabled=true
    blogs.email.entry.added.subject=${resource:com/liferay/portlet/blogs/dependencies/email_entry_added_subject.tmpl}
    blogs.email.entry.added.body=${resource:com/liferay/portlet/blogs/dependencies/email_entry_added_body.tmpl}
```

Liferay will *supposedly* use the templates in the specified paths (`com/liferay/portlet/blogs/dependencies/email_entry_added_subject.tmpl` and `com/liferay/portlet/blogs/dependencies/email_entry_added_body.tmpl`). The thing is, it's not very clear *what these paths are relative to*. Are these files relative to `$CATALINA_BASE`? For example, would the above configuration result in Liferay looking up `$CATALINA_BASE/com/liferay/portlet/blogs/dependencies/email_entry_added_body.tmpl` for creating the body of an email message? If this is not the case, where does Liferay lookup templates for Blog-related email messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I've found that you place the templates in the `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes` folder. Paths that you reference in the properties (e.g. `blogs.email.entry.added.body=${resource:com/liferay/portlet/blogs/dependencies/email_entry_added_body.tmpl}`) are *relative to the aforementioned classes folder*.

So, if I wanted Liferay to use a template file in the ff. relative path: `org/foo/my_email_entry_added_body.tmpl`, I would do two things:

1. Place the file in `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/org/foo/my_email_entry_added_body.tmpl`.
2. Add the following line to `$CATALINA_BASE/portal-ext-env.properties`: `blogs.email.entry.added.body=${resource:org/foo/my_email_entry_added_body.tmpl}`.

I consulted my co-worker and got a better understanding of why this is. The architecture of a Liferay application is such that it comes bundled with a Tomcat server. According to the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html), `WEB-INF/classes` is a directory that a web app deployed to a Tomcat server looks up for classes and resources:

> A class loader is created for each web application that is deployed in a single Tomcat instance. *All unpacked classes and resources in the /WEB-INF/classes directory of your web application, plus classes and resources in JAR files under the /WEB-INF/lib directory of your web application, are made visible to this web application, but not to other ones*.

Specifically, this folder is [high in priorty in the web app's classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8375656/5665947).

When you see Liferay code similar to `${resource:path/to/foo}`, it's looking up resources in its classpath. One of the paths in that classpath is `WEB-INF/classes`. Hence, if `path/to/foo` is placed in `WEB-INF/classes`, Liferay will find `path/to/foo` there.