# Classes or Jar, who wins?

Tags: java, web, classloader

Is it right, that in case of duplicate classes, 
the one in "classes" will be taken?

Consider in a web application the class A will be available directly in

**WEB-INF/classes**

and a part of a jar in

**WEB-INF/lib**

Will the one in classes always win?

Comment: At least from my experience with different application servers and servlet containers I'd say "yes", but I am not sure if this is by definition or just by "common usage". Interesting question, though.

Comment: Apparently so. The following link may be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739302/web-inf-classes-vs-web-inf-lib

Comment: as far as I know this is not specified in the standard. different application servers behave very differently. weblogic and jboss will pick the jar provided by the appserver first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the class path - the classpath entry that comes first will initially win. Also, if there are multiple class loaders, a class loader that has loaded the the dependent class will be tried first. It should not depend on if classes are in the jar or not. Documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/load.html).

In general, do not do this as having multiple classes under same name is a true recipe for disaster.

Comment: **multiple classes under same name is a true recipe for disaster** sure, but what else could be done in a complex web app (100+ jars), when you do not control the building of jars?